# Paint or Hide Control Box for Borderless Form while maximize and minimize

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I've attached a small example about the issue. How can I hide the control box completely during Maximize and Minimize the Borderless Form

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;

namespace TalkTime
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {

        int message = m.Msg;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCPAINT:
                {

                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    return;
                }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x20000;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I put the thread to show where is the problem exactly.

The black rectangle which is I guess related to the controlbox and form name will appear before the form while I want to hide it completely while maximizing and minimizing.

[image: Example]

Comment: A borderless form doesn't have a control box.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the issue. When restoring a border-less `Form` from minimized state, a ghost of a title-bar shows at top-left of the window for a very short time.

**Reproducing the issue**

To reproduce the problem, it's enough to create a border-less form by setting `FormBorderStyle` property to `None` and then minimize and restore it in a timer. Start the program by showing the form and look at top-left of the window, after restore.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
        this.Text = "Some Text";
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        timer.Tick += (x, y) =>
        {
            if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            else
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

**Workaround**

Here is the workaround which I used to remove that flicker. It's enough to add the event handler to above `Form1` class and register it for `Activated` event `this.Activated += Form1_Activated;`.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        this.Hide();
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized && !Visible)
            this.Show();
    }));
}
```

Comment: In My tests, I removed `CreateParams` override and performed `Minimize` and `Maximize` and `Restore` using 3 buttons on form. Also after minimizing in both maximized and normal state, used task-bar to restore form to previous state.

Comment: I'm using CreateParams to be able to use restore and minimize from task bar button. Still I've the same issue based on your suggestion. @Reza Aghaei

Comment: I posted the reproduction code and the workaround, you can simply check it.

Comment: And I don't want to use Show() Hide() methods because it is removing the task bar button for mements.

Comment: .. If you decrease the timer interval to 100ms you'll see that the problem still not solved. If you remove the timer and use window styles to enable WS_MINIMIZEBOX, and try to activate it from task-bar you will see the issue there.

Comment: 100 ms is unreal test. In 100 ms interval you will see some other problems too. But in a real test you will never see the control box. Although it's not a perfect workaround, but it's working :)

Comment: Let me know if you find a better workaround or if you find the answer useful :)

Comment: I'm still testing and trying to reach the best result. I'll let you know soon

Comment: Good job, I'm curious to know a better workaround :)