# Setting WinForm background to a screenshot, black box appears in corner of window

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

I have a simple winforms app that, when maximized, takes a screenshot and sets the form's background image. If I minimize the form and then maximize it I get a black box in the top corner and I can't figure out where it is coming from. It is not present on the initial load of the form.

Where is this coming from?

This is .Net 4.7 with VS 2017

[image]

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (WindowState)
    {
        case FormWindowState.Normal:
            break;
        case FormWindowState.Minimized:
            break;
        case FormWindowState.Maximized:
            Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
            Size s = new Size(screenshot.Width, screenshot.Height);
            Graphics screenshotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
            screenshotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
            this.BackgroundImage = screenshot;
            screenshotGraphics.Dispose();
            Invalidate();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Designer:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(712, 594);
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MinimizeBox = false;
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.ShowIcon = false;
    this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
    this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
    this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
    this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);
    this.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseUp);
    this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

> Update

It only happens when I set FormBorderStyle to none, but that is how I need it.

Comment: Tried your code (commenting out the lines that set FormBorderStyle, MaximizeBox, MinimizeBox and ControlBox) I cannot reproduce the problem. So if it is not caused by the commented out properties then it is possibly caused by your video driver. I would try on a different machine if possible

Comment: I just had someone else try it and it does the same thing. We are on Windows 7, what are you using?

Comment: Win10Pro. Sorry no way to test here on Win7

Comment: I do not get the black box if I add the form border, etc. back in.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38881787/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks that solution (hack) works.

Comment: The code is simply making the screenshot at the wrong time.  The constructor or Load event handler is a good time, after that it gets to be murky with all of those visual style renderer quirks around.

Comment: @HansPassant, putting the code in either ctor or load causes the black box to flash and then disappear as described in the post supplied by Reza. So, it is better but still quirky.